# AWS Load Balancer controller created public-facing Load balancer bound to private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nlb

I wanted to share a situation that I've come across, which is puzzling me.

I found a Load Balancer created by the AWS Load Balancer Controller linked to one public subnet and one private subnet:

My subnets are adequately tagged to be automatically discovered by load balancers and ingress controllers, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html) and clarified in an ever more clear way in [this question](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-vpc-subnet-discovery/):

- Private subnets:

  - `kubernetes.io/cluster/<cluster_name>`: `shared`
  - `kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb`: `1`
- Public subnets:

  - `kubernetes.io/cluster/<cluster_name>`: `shared`
  - `kubernetes.io/role/elb`: `1`

My Load Balancer service in Kubernetes has the necessary annotations to state that it's a public-facing load balancer:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-attributes: access_logs.s3.enabled=true,access_logs.s3.bucket=<bucket_name>,access_logs.s3.prefix=<prefix>
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: <eip_allocation_id_1>, <eip_allocation_id_2>
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ip-address-type: ipv4
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: instance
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: <certificate_id>
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: '443'
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
```

The manual workaround was to delete the Elastic Load Balancer and the LoadBalancer service in Kubernetes and then re-creating the service, which launched a new Elastic Load Balancer, this time with the right subnets attached.

Comment: Sounds more like a bug in the kubernetes controller. Maybe ask here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues

Comment: Good point, @geertpt, I've asked also there  https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2782